# grails/spring security - issue on get all connected users

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I followed an article to get all connected users with spring securty in Grails, but it failed at `getAllPrincipals` method:
"Message: Cannot invoke method getAllPrincipals() on null object"

The code:

**resources.groovy**

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy

beans = {

    sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        maximumSessions = -1
    }

    concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
       expiredUrl = '/login/concurrentSession'
   }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**controller**

```
def sessionRegistry  
def users= new ArrayList<User>(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals())
```

http://classpattern.com/spring-security-sessionregistry-on-grails.html#.U5GICfl_uhF

Answer (score 0):

1. install templates: `grails install-templates`
2. `web.xml` will be found in : `src/templates/war`
3. Be sure that listener tag is before servlet tag :
4. Get all users  :

   `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().collect{User.get(it.id)}`

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem and what my solution is to declare sessionRegistry as variable class for example 
class DummyController {

```
def sessionRegistry

def index() {        
    def users= new ArrayList<User>(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals())

}
```

}